# errorElement type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. THANK YOU

Tags: react-native

I get this error when I run it on my phone, but it shows fine on web. I am working on this in expo snack. This project was previously working fine, I just checked back on it and I just got this error.
Here is the link to my project: https://snack.expo.dev/@skelaton_boss/blood-donation-app

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK after a tons of hour I found the problem from those lines:

```
<CheckBox
              value={this.state.isSelected} // <-- Burada this.state.isSelected değerini kullanın
              onValueChange={this.toggleCheckBox} // <-- Değer değiştiğinde toggleCheckBox fonksiyonunu çağırın
            />
```

inside `register.js`

Solution:

```
import { CheckBox } from 'react-native-elements'
```

then see the result